# Composition API State Management is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, state-management

I'm using composition api for state management but it's not reactive.

This is my store file :

```
import { readonly, reactive } from "@vue/reactivity";
const state = reactive({
    lang: "en",
    page: 1,
    words: [
        {
            word: "Hello",
            repeat: 92,
            sentences: [],
        },
        { word: "Love", repeat: 128 },
        { word: "Good", repeat: 50 },
        { word: "New", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Hello", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Love", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Good", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "New", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Hello", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Love", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Good", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "New", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Hello", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Love", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "Good", repeat: 12 },
        { word: "New", repeat: 12 },
    ],
});

const methods = {
    changePage(i: number): void {
        state.page = i;
    },
    emptyTheList() {
        state.words = [];
    },
};

export default { state, methods };
```

And this is a component that is using the injected store :

```
<template>
    <div class="btn-group bg-gray-50 mt-6 pt-6 pb-6 flex justify-center">
        <button class="btn" :id="wordsInfo.state.page">&#60;&#60;</button>
        <button
            class="btn"
            v-for="i in numberOfPages"
            v-bind:key="i"
            :class="page === i && 'btn-active'"
            @click="changePage(i)"
        >
            {{ i }}
        </button>
        <button class="btn">&#62;&#62;</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref, computed, inject } from "vue";

export default {
    name: "WordCardsPagination",
    props: {
        func: Function,
    },
    setup(props, context) {
        console.log(props.func);
        const wordsInfo = inject("wordsInfo");
        const numberOfPages = computed(() => {
            return Math.ceil(wordsInfo.state.words.length / 12);
        });
        const page = ref(wordsInfo.state.page);

        const changePage = (i) => {
            wordsInfo.methods.changePage(i);
            page.value = wordsInfo.state.page;
        };
        return {
            numberOfPages,
            wordsInfo,
            page,
            changePage,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

the code above runs with no problem but if instead of `page`, `wordsInfo.state.page` is used page ref is removed :

```
<button
            class="btn"
            v-for="i in numberOfPages"
            v-bind:key="i"
            :class="wordsInfo.state.page === i && 'btn-active'"
            @click="wordsInfo.methods.changePage(i)"
        >
            {{ i }}
        </button>
```

the component is not reactive anymore, even though `console.log` shows that the value has changed

Comment: You are importing `reactive` in your store but actually not using it anywhere. Is that intentional ?

Comment: @MichalLevý i did use it but it made no difference, removed it when i was trying different soloutions.

Comment: Well without it, `state` will not be reactive for sure...

Comment: @MichalLevý sure. edited the code but still not working.

Comment: Why do you make a `ref` from a `ref`? Since reactive traverses the object until it has a scalar value and puts a `ref` in its place. So `wordsInfo.state.page`  is already a `ref`, and you stick it again in `ref`. Or maybe I am mistaken now something. I may be thinking of `toRefs`.

Comment: It should. I do not see any problem. Except that the code is weird mix of attempted solutions. Maybe you should clean it up and also create runnable [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ...for example on Codesandbox/Codepen

Comment: @TheFool i know that it should but it's not.
without the ref classes don't change dynamically

Comment: It is a long shot and probably not an issue but just in case....try to always import from "vue" instead of "@vue/reactivity" (as in your store)

Comment: @MichalLevý Wow it worked. thank you very much.
post it as an answer so i can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not 100% sure this should be an answer but maybe it will help some people in the future...

In this case problem was in the import used in the "store" file - `import { readonly, reactive } from "@vue/reactivity"` while the rest of the app was using `import { ... } from 'vue'`

So as a result the "store" was using different Vue module (reactivity code) than the rest of the app. It is hard to say exactly why without knowing much more about the OP setup but as a rule of thumb try to stick with `import { xx } from "vue"` and do not mix it up!